# Identifying military portrait found in Texas?

Tags: photo-identification, texas, portraits

[image]

We have this portrait and have been trying to identify it with no avail.

The family is from Goliad, Texas, if that helps.

Do you have any thoughts about the year, country, what the uniform represents, etc?

Comment: Is the painting signed, or is the identity of the painter known?

Comment: No, no signature and no knowledge of the painter. It is hanging in a gilded frame and has no provenance.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that the person featured belongs to the family who own the portrait?

Comment: No, that is sort of what prompted this search. The owners are in their 90s and did not have information on how they acquired it but wanted to learn about it. One of the owners said she remembers someone once saying it's a naval uniform, but it could have been a wild guess.
(I should say, they did not purchase it. It has been in the family but they do not know the history)

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced this is a military uniform, although it is certainly military-esque. There is no obvious symbol of rank or unit, no sword or sash. The general style of the uniform, especially the high, stiff collar, are very reminiscent of U.S. Army uniforms circa 1830. However, the epaulets look wrong and buttons on the front should be far more obvious. I'm thinking maybe an officer on a merchant ship? Is the family originally from Texas, or did they come from elsewhere?

Comment: Thank you for your information, it helps us to have an approximate year and country to go on! It seems like perhaps it's a "gentleman's portrait," meant to look as if he's an officer.
The family is originally from Goliad and Hardin, TX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That jacket is very much like this stable jacket in the British National Army Museum [image: the stable jacket]
described [here](https://collection.nam.ac.uk/detail.php?q=searchType%3Dsimple%26resultsDisplay%3Dlist%26simpleText%3DDragoons%2Buniform&pos=14&total=24&page=1&acc=1951-12-83-1)
and the stable jacket of the Fife and Forfar Imperial Yeomanry shown [here](http://www.paoyeomanry.co.uk/LYGeorgian.htm).

It says in the description of the jacket that it "was often donned by cavalry officers during service overseas". Maybe that is why it appears in a portrait in Texas?

Comment: Bill, It looks like you found it! My apologies for not seeing your comment earlier. 
The owners of the portrait will be so pleased that they now have some sort of history to accompany the portrait, even if it is a (very) educated guess.
Thank you so much!